# find a holomorphic map $f:\mathbb{D} \to\mathbb{D}$ such that $f(0)=0,f(\frac{1}{3})=0$.

Tags: complex-analysis

find a holomorphic map $f:\mathbb{D} \to\mathbb{D}$ such that $f(0)=0,f(\frac{1}{3})=0$.

$f(z)=0$  is one such map. i wonder is this the only one ,

Answer (score 3):

Any function $f(z) := \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_kz^k$ will satisfy this if the $a_k$ are chosen such that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \lvert a_k\rvert\leq 1$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_k}{3^k} = 0$. The first condition is even more restrictive than necessary, but it guarantees that the series for $f$ converges and that $\lvert f\rvert\leq 1$ on $\mathbb{D}$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider
$$f(z)=z\times \frac{3z-1}{3-z}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(z) = C\sin(3\pi z)$. For sufficiently small $C$, $f$ is a holomoprhic function from $\mathbb{D}$ to $\mathbb{D}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f \colon D \to D$ holomorphic such that $f(a) = 0$ for some $a\in D$. Consider the diffeo of $D$ 
$$\phi_a \ \colon z \mapsto \frac{z - a}{1- \bar{ a} z}$$
Assume that $f(a) = 0$. Note that $\phi_a(a) = 0$, so $\phi_{a}^{-1}(0)= a$. We conclude
$$f \circ \phi_a^{-1} \colon D \to D,\ \  f \circ\phi_a^{-1}(0) = 0$$
By Schwarz lemma we conclude 
$$|f( \phi_{a}^{-1}(z) )| \le |z|$$ or, equivalently
$$|f(w)| \le | \phi_a(w)|$$ for all $w \in D$. Moreover, either
$\frac{f}{\phi_a}$ is either a  function from $D$ to $D$, or a constant of norm $1$.

Now we see that any function $f \colon D \to D$ that vanishes at $a_1$, $\ldots$, $a_n$ ( distinct points in $D$) is of the form 
$$f = g\cdot \prod_{k=1}^n \phi_{a_k} $$ where $g$ is either a function from $D$ to $D$, or a constant of norm $1$.